# Cannot Make Outbound Calls from Amazon EC2 VPC

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, outbound

I just started a new instance and deployed a very simple Java app to try to connect to MongoDB Atlas and the app is not able to connect. The same app is working fine locally. This is a general purpose instance in a VPC and not a classic. Is there a configuration to enable outbound calls? I checked the routing table and there is no rules to block any outbound calls. The attached image also show public IP, but I can't actually ping the server, but I can connect through ssh.

[image]

I have also tried assigning Elastic IP to an instance and that didn't work either.

[image: Elastic IP Assigned to Instance]

---

Update:

It turned out the issue was with MongoDB for this case. Based on what I saw online, it let me to thing this was an issue with Amazon VPC, but it was actually an issue with the whitelist on Mongo DB Atlas. I didn't realize that was the case since connection from my local was working even though it's not supposed to.

You DO NOT need a NAT server to send an outbound call.

Comment: Sounds like it is in a private subnet. Or maybe you didn't assign a public IP address to the instance. Or perhaps you VPC route to your Internet gateway is missing or incorrect.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the public IP, which I can't actually ping. I can connect to the server using ssh though.

Comment: "You DO NOT need a NAT server to send an outbound call" in your case, no as you have a public ip address.  If a host has no public ip address then a NAT is required

Comment: That's correct. However, there are so many posts around the internet stated otherwise. That's what causing the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Atlas actually now has VPC peering which will no longer require you to whitelist 0.0.0.0/0

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ACL's for that subnet allow `0.0.0.0/0`

Make sure you can ping www.google.com from within the instance

Check your subnet routes and ensure that it has a route for `0.0.0.0/0` to the internet gateway.